# Gin router: path segment conflicts with existing wildcard

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to make my app to serve below things.

- a.com => serve /www to a browser so that the browser can seek /www/index.html)
- a.com/js/mylib.js => serve /www/js/mylib.js to a browser
- a.com/api/v1/disk => typical REST API which returns JSON
- a.com/api/v1/memory => another API

I made a code like below:

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.Static("/", "/www")

    apiv1 := r.Group("api/v1")
    {
        apiv1.GET("/disk", diskSpaceHandler)
        apiv1.GET("/memory", memoryHandler)
        apiv1.GET("/cpu", cpuHandler)
    }

    r.Run(":80")
}
```

When I run the code, it panics:

```
panic: path segment '/api/v1/disk' conflicts with existing wildcard '/*filepath' in path '/api/v1/disk'
```

I understand why it panics, but I have no idea how to fix.

Just two things comes up in my mind:

1. Use NoRoute() function which will handle other than /api/v1 group path(don't know how exactly I implement that)
2. Use middleware. There is static middlewhere https://github.com/gin-gonic/contrib but the code is not working on Windows(https://github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/issues/91)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a limitation in Gin. https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/388

Comment: This isn't a Gin limitation, instead is a httprouter's feature: https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/issues/12#issuecomment-46121392

Answer (score 23):

This is an [**intended feature**](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/issues/12#issuecomment-46121392) of Gin's underlying router implementation. Routes are matched on prefixes, so any path param or wildcard **in the same position** as another existing path segment will result in a conflict.

In this particular Q&A, the method [`RouterGroup.Static`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#RouterGroup.Static) adds a wildcard `/*filepath` to the route you serve from. If that route is root `/`, **the wildcard will conflict with every other route you declare**.

#### What to do then?

You must accept that there is no straightforward solution, because that's just how Gin's router implementation works. If you can't accept a workaround then you might have to change HTTP framework. The comments mention Echo as an alternative.

**1. If you CAN change your route mappings**

The best workaround is no workaround, and instead embracing Gin's design. Then you can simply add a unique prefix to the static files path: `r.Static("/static", "/www")`. This doesn't mean you change your local directory structure, only what path prefix gets mapped to it. Request URLs have to change.

**2. Wildcard conflict with one or few other route**

Let's say that your router has only these two routes:

```html
/*any
/api/foo
```

In this case you might get away with a an intermediary handler and manually check the path param:

```
r.GET("/*any", func(c *gin.Context) {
    path := c.Param("any")
    if strings.HasPrefix(path, "/api") {
        apiHandler(c) // your regular api handler
    } else {
        // handle *any
    }
})
```

**3. Wildcard conflict with many other routes**

Which one is best depends on your specific situation and directory structure.

**3.1 using `r.NoRoute` handler**; this may work but is a bad hack.

```
r.NoRoute(gin.WrapH(http.FileServer(gin.Dir("static", false))))
r.GET("/api", apiHandler)
```

This will serve files from `static` (or whatever other dir) **BUT** it will also attempt to serve assets for all non-existing routes under the `/api` group. E.g. `/api/xyz` will be handled by `NoRoute` handler. This may be acceptable, until it isn't. E.g. if you just happen to have a folder named `api` among your static assets.

**3.2 using a middleware**;

For example, you can also find [`gin-contrib/static`](https://github.com/gin-contrib/static/blob/master/static.go):

```
// declare before other routes
r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("www", false)))
```

This middleware is slightly more sophisticated, but it suffers from the same limitation. Namely:

- if you have a dir named like your API route among the static assets, it will lead to infinite redirection (can mitigate with `Engine#RedirectTrailingSlash = false`)
- even without infinite redirection, the middleware will check the local FS first, and only if it finds nothing will proceed to the next handler in chain. This means you are making a **system call at each request** to check if a file exists. (or at least this is what `gin-contrib/static` does, as shown below)

```
    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        fname := "static" + c.Request.URL.Path
        if _, err := os.Stat(fname); err == nil {
            c.File(fname)
            c.Abort() // file found, stop the handler chain
        }
        // else move on to the next handler in chain
    })
    r.GET("/api", apiHandler)
    r.Run(":5555")
```

**3.3 using a Gin sub-engine**; this may be an OK choice if you have a lot of potential conflicts, e.g. a wildcard on `/` and complex API routes with groups and whatnot. Using a sub-engine will give you more control over this, but the implementation still feels hacky. An example based on [`Engine.HandleContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.HandleContext):

```
func main() {
    apiEngine := gin.New()
    apiG := apiEngine.Group("/api")
    {
        apiG.GET("/foo", func(c *gin.Context) { c.JSON(200, gin.H{"foo": true})})
        apiG.GET("/bar", func(c *gin.Context) { c.JSON(200, gin.H{"bar": true})})
    }

    r := gin.New()
    r.GET("/*any", func(c *gin.Context) {
        path := c.Param("any")
        if strings.HasPrefix(path, "/api") {
            apiEngine.HandleContext(c)
        } else {
            assetHandler(c)
        }
    })
    r.Run(":9955")
}
```

#### Wrap up

If you can, redesign your routes. If you can't, this answer presents three possible workarounds of increasing complexity. As always, the limitations may or may not apply to your specific use case. YMMV.

If none of this works for you, maybe leave a comment to point out what is your use case.

Comment: I stumbled on this fantastic answer when trying (and failing) to do the following: have two independently set routes for static files, e.g. "/assets" and "/media". Everything worked when I just had "/assets". When I added static routes for "/media", those didn't work! My thought was: maybe Gin can only deal with ONE static route, not more than one? But of course both are handled with "*filepath" at the end. The answer is the same as what you've given: sure, Gin can handle as many static routes as you want, so long as they don't conflict with each other, something which was not that obvious!

Answer (score -3):

you should use static middleware, see its example:

https://github.com/gin-contrib/static#canonical-example

```
r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("/tmp", false)))
```